Fitting imported data to equation and extracting K values
I am working with a set of data:
Time = [1, 1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5, 6.25, 7.5, 8.75, 10]
AB = [0.041355887, 0.228856274, 0.283712222, 0.401528071, 0.450842768, 0.514348728,  0.550876642, 0.61845291, 0.663312161]

and want to fit it to this equation:
AB(t) = k1(1 - e^(-k2*t))
And ultimately be able to extract k1 and k2 from this fitting.
This is code which I have begun trying so far:
import io
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BindData = pd.read_csv('binding.csv', index_col=0)
data_array = np.recfromcsv('binding.csv', names = ['Time','AB'])

def func(AB, t):
    AB = k1(1 - exp(-k2*t))
    return AB

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, df.Time, df.AB, method="lm")

But I am having troubles running it without k1 and k2 being defined. I think I organized it incorrectly for what I am hoping to accomplish, which is ultimately being able to see a plot with the original data, as well as the fitted curve, and getting the numerical values for k1 and k2. I am very new to python and would love any advice anyone has to offer!

The function was defined so far as:
def func(AB, t):
    AB = k1(1 - exp(-k2*t))
    return AB 

There are some mistakes that need improving for the fitting to work:

k1(1 - exp(-k2*t)) is missing a multiplication after k1
the expression exp is not known in Python, hence it needs to be called from a library. For example numpy.exp, or np.exp for short
The function defintion requires the coefficients as well. Think of functions as black boxes, they take inputs and spit out outputs. Everything within the function needs to be defined inside the function or passed to it. Hence, the function definition should change to def func(t, k1, k2):.
Also notice how I removed AB from the definition. We actually want to return the fitted values that approximates AB.

Now that we got the function correctly, we can go with a pretty standard fitting:
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def exponentialGrowth(t, k1, k2):
    return k1 * (1 - np.exp(-k2 * t))
Time = np.array([1, 1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5, 6.25, 7.5, 8.75, 10])
AB = np.array([0.041355887, 0.228856274, 0.283712222, 0.401528071, 0.450842768, 0.514348728,  0.550876642, 0.61845291, 0.663312161])
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponentialGrowth, Time, AB)
print(f"Fitted k1 = {round(popt[0],2)}\nFitted k2 = {round(popt[1],2)}")

The print line outputs:
Fitted k1 = 0.78
Fitted k2 = 0.18

We scatter the raw points and we plot the fitted function as a line:
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(Time, AB)
plt.plot(Time, exponentialGrowth(Time, *popt), "k--")
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("AB")
plt.legend(["Raw", "Fitted"])

We get the following:

Feel free to ask any questions about this approach. Hope this helps!

Great, thank you so much, this was super helpful! Just curious, when you are showing the k-values with the print function, can you explain how you structured the code in the parentheses? Or why did you specify k1 and k2 in that way?

Hey @HAILEYRUDE, there's a whole lot of ways on how to print out stuff in Python. If you haven't already, do take an introductory tutorial from a good source on Python and printing. Also, in case this answer helped you, please remember to accept the answer to close the question
